# How do you 'OR' arguments in assembly language?

Tags: c, assembly

For example (in C)...

```
int main() {
    fxn(EXAMPLE_VALUE | EXAMPLE_VAL | EXAMPLE_V);
}
```

How would one do this in assembly language?

Comment: Probably using the OR instruction or one with a similar name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as in C.

```
global main
main:
    mov    edi, EXAMPLE_VALUE | EXAMPLE_VAL | EXAMPLE_V
    call   fxn             ; AMD64 SysV ABI: first arg in rdi
    xor    eax,eax
    ret
```

(Or if this wasn't `main`, with an implicit `return 0`, optimize the tail-call to `jmp fxn`.)

asm syntax allows complex expressions, as long as everything is an assemble-time constant.  adding/subtracting link-time constants (e.g. symbol addresses) to other constants is also usually allowed, e.g. `[ static_buf + 10 ]`

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to NASM docs, etc. etc.

Assemblers for other architectures are similar; this isn't x86-specific.

Comment: Many thanks. Also I checked and found out that ORing integer arguments just adds them together.

Comment: @Sam: addition is XOR with carry between bits in the `1^1` case, so yes, it gives the same results as OR in the no-carry case (e.g. with constants that each have a single bit set).  OR is preferred in this case to better express the semantic meaning of setting multiple bits in a bit-mask.